# How to add a custom tab bar to a project oriented by navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

**The problem:**

I'm working on a project that contains multiple storyboards and all the navigation in the SBs are done using navigation controllers. However, I also want to add a tab bar to switch between storyboards. I need to use a custom tab bar because of its appearance.

**What I need to know:**

1. Should I subclass UITabBarController or just go with a view and a manager?
2. If I need to subclass the UITabBarController, how do I link the buttons in the custom tab bar (.xib) to the tab bar controller? (Delegate/Protocol, link outlets directly...)
3. I'm working with xibs and storyboards, which is the best approach to use them as much as possible to solve this?

**This is what I'm trying to achieve:**

[image]

Comment: What kind of customizations do you need? You might not need to subclass the tab bar controller or make your own.

Comment: Click on the navigation controllers you wish to embed in a tab bar then go to Editor > Embed In > Tab Bar Controller

Comment: @AaronBrager I added a picture of what it should look like. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the look in the screenshot, I would just use a regular `UITabBarController`. To create the large, red button in the middle, just make a `UIButton` and add it above the `UITabBar`.

You can see some sample code in the [open-source `RaisedCenterTabBar` project](https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/RaisedCenterTabBar), although I would use auto-layout instead of manual layout to position the button.

You won't be able to use a storyboard to add the button, but it'll still be a lot less work than reinventing or subclassing `UITabBarController`.